# Optimal implementation of a word finding android application

Tags: java, android, kotlin, set

I am developing an android application that solves the following problem: Given a word such as 'meat', find all english words comprising of characters in 'meat', that is 'mate', 'tame', 'meta', 'team' and 'meat'.

The problem is designing it optimally. The current implementation works like so:

1. A collection of 10,000 english words are obtained from a json file and stored in a room sqlite database  at app installation.
2. When the user searches for a word, this is what happens:

   1. The application creates a set of all possible permutations from the word the user entered by shuffling it 5000 times (technically 5000 * wordlength).
   2. The application queries the database for a list of all the words stored in the word table.
   3. The application intersects the two sets to find matches.

The problem is that the application lags when the user is searching for a word on a real device. It takes a long time to respond when the word is more than 6 letters.

I am looking for a better way. The ideal solution must somehow do the following:

1. Zero delay. The application must not lag as the user types in a word.
2. The application must respond normally for long words.

Comment: "It takes a long time to respond when the word is more than 6 letters" -- use [Android Studio's profilers](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile), or perhaps simple `Log` calls, to determine where you are spending your time. Then, determine what you can do to improve the performance of your slow spots. If you cannot determine how to improve the performance, ask a separate question with a [mcve] and ask for help on performance improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can write function getHashForm(word: String) that has to return the same word but with letters ordering according to ABC. For example, both your words "mate", "tame", "meta" has the same "hash-form" - "aemt".
2. You can keep in your sql database not only original words, but also their "hash-form" (you have to obtain this hash-form with the help of "getHashForm" while loading from JSON).
3. When you search your alike-words for "meat", the first thing you have to do - is to get its "hash-form" with the help of "getHashForm"- "aemt". And then to query your database in one shot (with just a "select * from your_table as yt where yt.hashform = :[hash_you_get]" in pseudocode) without loops or shuffling.

Comment: Thank you. How do I implement getHashForm

Comment: I have found out how to get the hash. `val hash = word.toList().sorted().hashCode()` Thank you very much